# how to get the selected value using the name attribute in HTMLDropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on this website in MVC and I wanted to give my users list of hotels to select by retrieving the hotel's records from my database in my controller and pass it using `ViewBag` to my view. 
Here's the code in my view

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Hotel", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

And i want to pass the hotel that is selected to other action method with the name attribute.

Comment: Basically, you must need a list of SelectionListItem and an int index please see this post for more details http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/4d9083/binding-dropdownlist-in-mvc-in-various-ways-in-mvc-with-data/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the controller

```html
public ActionResult Create ()
{
   ViewBag.Hotels = new SelectList(db.hotel,"Id_Hotel","Name_Hotel");
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create( int Hotel )
{
   var hotel = db.hotel.Find(Hotel);
}
```

in the view

```html
@Html.DropDownList("Hotel", ViewBag.Hotels as SelectList , htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```